# Google Maps Api autocomplete: contains instead of starts with

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

We are using Google Places API for getting some locations in a map. The thing is, we have some issues with autocomplete (I believe related with browser language) because if you want to look for places in Panama City, you can write "Panama" and it will return "Panama City" as a prediction result. But, if your browser is in Spanish (our users speak Spanish), the user could write "Panama" and we would like to have "Ciudad de Panama" as a result, but we don't. The option in this case is to look for "Ciudad de Pa" for getting the result, but this is something that we don't want to have.

May be, the option is getting the predictions by "contains" method, instead of "starts with". Is it possible? Any other idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Google Place Autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) results are already based on what you said "contains" method. I tried to get what you want and use **"Ciudad de Panama"** as my input and get many results not only start with input **"Ciudad de Panama"** but also get results like **"Panamá, Doctores, Ciudad de México, México"**.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Ciudad%20de%20Panama&types=address&language=es&key=your_api_key
```

So I think Autocomplete API does not return all results that contains what you search. Also, I think it gives priority in the search string what word you input. For example, as you observe on the results in the above request, I search the word **"Ciudad de Panamá"**, the first result will give the exact word, the second and the rest will not. So if you use **"Panama"** as input. It will prioritize to results an address that contains **"Panama"** itself than a word that contains Panama as second or third word in the results.**(xxxxx xxxx Panama)**

Comment: Hi. I tried that URL directly for "Panama". I get only 5 results and none of them is "Ciudad de Panama", what we need. These are the places in the result: 1) “Panamá, Puno, Perú”, 2) “Panamá”, 3) “Panama, Huancayo, Junín, Perú”, 4) “Panama, Distrito de Barranco, Lima, Perú”, 5) “Panamá, Guayaquil, Guayas, Ecuador”

Comment: So, the question is if is there any way to make it work for our interests? Because, as I mentioned, we need to get "Ciudad de Panama" matching for "Panama" search.

Comment: Like I said, Autocomplete API works like this. It gives priority on the word/string that you input. So I think you cannot get "Ciudad de Panama" when typing the word "Panama".

Comment: For a better example, you want to get the word "New Mexico", but you cannot get it if you only search for the word "Mexico". Because the search results give way to the word/address that has "Mexico" in the first word of the address. So if you really want to achieve the result "New Mexico" you need to type "New Mex" as your input. So in other words, I sad to say that you cannot get "Ciudad de Panama" unless you input the word "Ciudad de Pan". Also for more information the Google Places API Web Service returns only up to 5 results. I hope I explained it better and it helps you :)

Comment: Ok, I understand. So, may be Google Maps API is not what we need, due to how autocomplete works. Thanks for your answer.